# Is there a way to merge rsync and tar (compress)?

Tags: compression, tar, rsync

NOTE: I am using the term **tar** loosely here. I mean compress whether it be tar.gz, tar.bz2, zip, etc.

Is there a flag for `rsync` to negotiate the changed files between source/destination, tar the changed source files, send the single tar file to the destination machine and untar the changed files once arrived?

I have millions of files and remotely `rsync`ing across the internet to AWS seems very slow.

I know that `rsync` has a compression option (`z`), but it's my understanding that that compresses changed files on a per file basis. If there are many small files, the overhead of sending a 1KB as opposed to a 50KB file is still the bottleneck.

Also, simply tarring the whole directory is not efficient either as it will take an hour to archive

Comment: Please make sure to mention why you downvote so that users may write better formatted questions in the future

Answer (score 2):

You can use the rsyncable option of [gzip](http://gzip.org/) or [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) to compress the tar file to .gz format. (You will likely have to find a patch for gzip to add that. It's already part of pigz.)

The option partitions the resulting gzip file in a way that permits rsync to find only the modified portions for much more efficient transfers when only some of the files in the .tar.gz file have been changed.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for exact same thing as you and I landed on using borg.

`tar cf - -C $DIR . | borg create $REPO::$NAME`

tar will still read entire folder so you won't avoid a read penalty versus just rsyncing two dirs (since I believe rsync uses tricks to avoid reading each file for changes), but you will avoid the write penalty because borg will only write blocks it hasn't encountered before. Also borg auto compresses so no need for xz/gzip. Also, if borg is installed on both ends it won't send over superfluous data either since the two borgs can let each other know what they have versus don't.

If avoiding that read penalty is crucial for you, you could possibly use rsync to use its tricks to just tell you which files changed, create a difftar and send that to borg, but then getting borg to merge archives is whole second headache. You'd likely end up creating a filter that removes paths that were deleted from the original archive and then creating a new archive of just file additions/changes. And then you'd have to do that for each archive recursively. In the end it will create the original archive by extracting each version in sequence, but like I said a total headache.